# reassigning an object with operate overloaded objects

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a class which it's objects are able to be added together and be assigned to another **existed** object like this(a1 is an initialized object):

```
numcpp<float> a2 = a1;  
a2 = a1 + 2;
```

but I get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
test.cpp:81:13: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘numcpp<float>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘numcpp<float>’  
a1 = a2d2 + 2;  
     ~~~~~^~~
In file included from test.cpp:1:  
numcpp.h:283:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void numcpp<T>::operator=(numcpp<T>&) [with T = float]’
void numcpp<T>::operator=(numcpp &obj)
     ^~~~~~~~~
```

Then I tried this code:

```
numcpp<float> a2 = a1;    
&a2 = a1 + 2;
```

And I got:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
test.cpp:81:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment  
&a1 = a2d2 + 2;  
             ^
```

Here are operator functions I used in my test code:

```
template <class T>
numcpp<T> numcpp<T>::operator+(T n)
{
  numcpp<T> obj(i, j, k);
  for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    obj.set(array[x] + n, x);
  }

  return obj;
};


template <class T>
void numcpp<T>::operator=(numcpp &obj)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    this->set(obj.get(x), x);
  }
  return;
};
```

Comment: `operator=` should be taking its input as a const reference, not a non-const reference: `void numcpp<T>::operator=(const numcpp &obj)` That will allow an implicit conversion from any type that `numcpp` can be constructed from.  Also, `operator+` should be marked as `const` since it does not modify the contents of `*this`, and it should be callable on non-const and const `numcpp` objects alike: `numcpp<T> numcpp<T>::operator+(T n) const`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your operator= overload you want to take a non-const reference.

Your expression `a2 = a1 + 2` a2 is an lvalue, a1 is also an lvalue but the 2 is an rvalue and it will be implicitly converted to a numcpp<int> object. Then the a1 and the converted 2 is added together, which is an rvalue. After that you try to call the operator= which takes a non-const reference, which cannot bind to an rvalue. Change the operator= to take a const reference.

You should check what an lvalue and an rvalue is.

But even after the const modification your code will not compile, because you must specify the template parameter of the numcpp object in the equals overload.

For more info look up templates on cppreference, but if you are a beginner don't start with templates or at least don't dive too deep at first because it is kinda a sub programing language of C++ and it can be daunting even for experienced people.

That second example you tried is not compiling because you take the memory address of a1, which is by definition is an rvalue and you try to modify it.